# React three fiber

Tags: react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm sorry if I'm going to speak strangely, I use a translator.
I'm new to react three fiber.
I have a task to make a constructor similar to [this](https://www.teeshot.fotura.co)

I ran into a problem that I don't know how to determine the coordinates of the cursor location on a 3d model. This is necessary in order to properly overlay the uploaded image on it.

I managed to find out that this can be done via raycaster or [cycleraycaster](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#cycleraycast) from the react drei library, but I don't understand how to use it correctly for this task.
Could someone tell me how to do it correctly, or maybe someone has an example of a similar task =)